# Search result page not displaying items defined in different default.xml files for theme

Tags: magento2, theme, search, catalogsearch, theme-fallback

I am working on developing a theme. I overrode the **default.xml** layout file for theme in my, ***VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/override/base/default.xml***. In this file, I have defined some overrides which works fine with other modules, except the CatalogSearch module. When I try to search anything on my theme, it gives me page with blank / null layout. To get the theme specific changes on the search result page, I need to create CatalogSearch module and copy the changes from the **override/base/default.xml** file and place them to **VENDOR/THEME/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml** file. I do not know why the layout does not work with search but works well with all other modules.

**NOTE:**  I found that , for some reason, the common items which are defined to be displayed on every page for the theme and defined in *default.xml* file in other modules; are not displayed on search result page. Do I need to tweak anything on **catalogseach_result_index.xml** file to pick stuff specified in **default.xml** files?

Thanks in advance.